# Explanation of Array[i, j] = rnd.Next(0, 100);

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, matrix

I have a code:

```
        int[,] mas = new int[5, 5];
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                mas[i, j] = rnd.Next(0, 100);
                Console.Write(mas[i, j] + "\t");
            }
                Console.WriteLine();
```

but i can`t understand what mas[i, j] means. Like first our matrix is filled by default 0, but we inject i and j into our array and then i and j are filled by random numbers from 0 to 100? And what does"\t" mean?

Comment: "\t" is a TAB character when writing to the console.

Comment: If you consult the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.next?view=netframework-4.8#System_Random_Next_System_Int32_System_Int32_) - which is very easy to do - you'll see that `Random.Next(0, 100)` picks a number between 0 and 99.  The max value parameter is exclusive.

Comment: _Like first our matrix is filled by default 0, but we inject i and j into our array and then i and j are filled by random numbers from 0 to 100?_ What injecting? It's been a while since I've done any C#, but this looks like some pretty standard array indexing/access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a coordinate to a position in a rectangular array (in your case a 5x5). This code will loop over ever row, and every column in each row, putting a random number in each

You start out with everything set to 0 when you make a `new int[5,5]`:

```
   0  1  2  3  4 
-+--------------
0| 0  0  0  0  0
1| 0  0  0  0  0
2| 0  0  0  0  0
3| 0  0  0  0  0
4| 0  0  0  0  0
```

And after the loops have finished running you end up with every array slot set to a random number:

```
   0  1  2  3  4 
-+--------------
0|22 75 43 97 45 
1|11  4 97 28 33
2|84 92 51 89 32
3|32 54 63 91 60
4|71  2 39 74  1
```

`i` and `j` are not filled with random numbers; they are incremented by the loops so both will cycle through 0 to 5, `i` will do it once and `j` will do it 5 times:

```
i, j
0, 0
0, 1
0, 2
0, 3
0, 4
1, 0 <=j restarted from 0 when i went to 1
1, 1
...
4, 2
4, 3
4, 4
```

This is how each coordinate in the array is filled with a random number given by `rnd.Next()`

---

`'\t'` is a TAB character